昔からやっている VS 昔からやっていた
Based on my understanding of tense / aspect, 昔からやっていた should mean that at the time of speaking the action/habit described by the verb should no longer be continuing, whereas with 昔からやっている, the action/habit is still ongoing, e.g. someone has been doing something.
However, I sometimes find examples of 昔からやっていた used to describe actions/habits that are still ongoing.
Here is one example from the web - from a restaurant review:

平戸でおいしい店と聞くと、こちらの店が結構上がってきます。昔からやっていたみたいで、ハンバーグ関係がおいしいと聞きます。

One more example - from a blog presenting an initiative known as 職業体験:

全国的に最近始まった授業のカリキュラムかと思いきや、福井県は昔からやっていたみたいです。

Are you familiar with this usage of ていた to talk about things that are still ongoing? How would you explain it? Is it always linked to a sense of "discovery", that is, something the speaker  found out at a later stage - as suggested by 思いきや in the second example?


Based on my understanding of tense / aspect, 昔からやっていた should mean that at the time of speaking the action/habit described by the verb should no longer be continuing, whereas with 昔からやっている, the action/habit is still ongoing, e.g. someone has been doing something.

No, this is wrong. ～ていた form is just past tense of ～ている. It indicates a progressive action (or completed action or habitual action, etc.) takes place in the past. Whether this action is still happening at the moment of speaking is irrelevant. This action could be still happening or already stopped some time ago.
Related questions:

Why「なっていた」is used here?

Question about ている ていた for explaining state for something



Thank you for your explanation. I still don't understand, though, why the speakers from the examples I posted would choose ていた over ている. Could you clarify that? Given the context, ている seems to me to be the most natural choice. Cf. 去年から日本語を勉強している。(from https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-continuous-form-teiru/).
Using ていた usually implies a point of view located in the past (as nicely illustrated in the graph by Naruto-san you linked), and I'm not sure why such point of view would be adopted in the examples above.

@DavideBordoni I cannot explain that well unfortunately. I think it is similar to the difference between ～と言っている and ～と言っていた. The latter sounds more neutral.

I see, thank you!
